# Is it safe to use single UDP socket for read/write from different threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I'm writing UDP server that serves several clients.
There are two kinds of threads run on server: listener thread (one thread) and handlers threads (several).
All threads use the same socket. Listener thread receives incoming datagrams and passes it to appropriate handler thread (one handler per client). Handler processes the message, creates response datagram and sends it to a client.
The questions:

1. May send operation be blocked since listener is waiting for data?
2. Is such approach correct?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. UDP is full-duplex, and so are Java `DatagramSockets`.

Comment: Handlers create response (datagram) and send it to client. Each client has it own "peer" handler.